# In R, do as.POSIXlt and strptime require different formats?

Tags: r, datetime, datetime-format, posixct, posixlt

Consider the following R console output.

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
> dh <- '2018-05-08 07:42:34 PM'
> as.POSIXlt(dh,'%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
[1] "2018-05-08 07:42:34"
> strptime(dh,'%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
[1] "2018-05-08 19:42:34 -03"
```

If both formats are identical, why doesn't `as.POSIXlt` recognize the 12-hour format properly? `dh` gives a time at night (7 PM), but the function is returning a time in the morning! `as.POSIXct` gives the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: One possibility from the documentation of `?as.POSIXlt`: "If format is specified, remember that some of the format specifications are locale-specific, and you may need to set the LC_TIME category appropriately via Sys.setlocale. This most often affects the use of %b, %B (month names) and %p (AM/PM)."

Comment: In *my* versions of R (3.3 and 3.4), your `as.POSIXlt` call produces several warnings. They might have something to do with the differences. (The second positional argument is different between the two functions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual mistake seems to be in the line;

```
as.POSIXlt(dh, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
```

It should be as:

```
as.POSIXlt(dh, format= '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
#[1] "2018-05-08 19:42:34 BST"
```

The 2nd argument for `strptime` is `format`. Hence, `strptime(dh,'%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')` works fine as it considers 2nd argument as `format`.

But 2nd argument for `as.POSIXlt` is `tz`. Hence, the text provided to be considered as `format` is taken up as `tz` and default `format` is used. That was resulting in unexpected value.